# Download PDF php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to force a pdf file to download. I have seen a couple of questions on stack about this. But when applied the solution does not seem to work for me.

The PDF file after output(using FPDF) does save and is view able directly on the server, but when I download or email the file out it shows as corrupt.

Can anybody please advise?

Code to download or email (depending on action required)

```
$pdf->output(ROOTDIR.'/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/statement.pdf');
    if($action=='print'){
        $file_name = 'statement.pdf';
        $file_url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/" . $file_name;
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
        readfile($file_url);
        return('Statement Generated. Starting download.');
        exit;
    }elseif($action=='mail'){
        require_once(ROOTDIR."/modules/addons/statement_generator/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = "localhost";  // specify main and backup server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = ""; // SMTP password

        $mail->From = $from_mail;
        $mail->FromName = $from_name;
        $mail->AddAddress($client_email, $name);                 // name is optional
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from_mail, $from_name);

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
        //$mail->AddAttachment(ROOTDIR.'/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/statement.pdf');         // add attachments
        $mail->AddAttachment(ROOTDIR.'/modules/addons/statement_generator/reports/statement.pdf', "Statement.pdf");    // optional name
        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->AltBody = $non_html_body;

        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
           return( "Message could not be sent. <p>"."Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo);
           exit;
        }

        return( "Message has been sent");
    }
```

Comment: Where do the `return` statement send those strings to? To the browser? Then you have your culprit...

Comment: @arkascha the return merely returns the message whether or not it was a success. and then I echo the return value on the page. Why?

Comment: That is your issue. To what "page" should that get echoed? You cannot send _two_ replies to a single request from a browser. How should that work? You actually send the PDF content and then that string right afterwards. The browser will treat both as a single reply, which will obviously result in an invalid document. Because that string is suddenly part of the PDF content.

Comment: I am not sure how or why, but removing the return value solved my problem... Can you elaborate if you know why?

Comment: I think I did above. Maybe try a reload :-)

Comment: I see it now. Thanks very much you were a great help. @arkascha